Getting all children where at least one sibling matches the query in Elasticsearch
I have a database of books written by various authors. I would like to query books based on some attribute (say title text), and return ALL the books by each author for whom at least one of their books matches the search. For example, if author 1 writes books A, B, and C, and the query is for A, it should return A, B, and C.
I am planning on using a parent/child relation with author as the parent and books as the child. I see two possible approaches.

Query by author using has_child. Get the results of authors who have at least one book that matches the search. Then in a second query, get the list of books belonging to each of those authors.

Some type of nested has_parent -> has_child to get all the books whose author has a book that matches the search. This can be done in one query, but I am wondering if it is even faster than doing two separate queries.


Is there any significant performance difference between these approaches? I tried implementing both solutions and got them to work, but I don't know enough about elasticsearch to decide which solution is better practice.

Generally, Elasticsearch is quite fast and running a second query to get what you need is acceptable when there is no other way.
However, in Elasticsearch, denormalization is a common practice. Instead of splitting data across multiple tables, you store all the relevant information in a single JSON document. An order document would contain the author information and the books' information together in one json document. As a general rule of thumb, storage can be cheaper than compute costs for joining data.
source: What is an Eleasticsearch index/Why is denormalized data key to faster data retrieval?

Given I do not have any idea what other relations you may have in your data, for just the case you've described above, you could use the Nested field type which takes an order document (in this case a single document for an author and his/her books) and splits it internally. This would allow you to have a link between author and books while adhering to the best practice of denormalization. You are allowed to have up to 10000 nested JSON objects (index.mapping.nested_objects.limit) contained in a single document by default (which I would stay way below this number for maximum performance), which is more than enough for books written by an author.
So to answer the question, I think, if you are starting from scratch, you should work on creating order documents that would help you search and retrieve information in one go.
